# How to use Android's File Chooser to pick from my app's folder

Tags: android, android-intent, filechooser

I am targeting Android 10 (SDK 30 or above)
and trying to allow the user to pick a file that the app has created.  The files are in the app's folder (in my case something like /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.SomePremiumTesting/files/logs )

These files were written by *this* app with calls like:

```
File myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir("logs"), filename);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
```

Trying to open File Chooser like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/json");

intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.SomePremiumTesting");

startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_TRACK_FILE);
```

fails with a "no activity found android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE: exception

If I eliminate the addCategory and the setType it'll open to the root.

How can I open a file picker to allow the user to choose one of the .json files I have created?

Comment: Why are you trying to use the file picker used to pick from the user's public files for picking from your app's own private files?

Answer (score 1):

On an Android 11 device even file managers like the Files app have no access to apps getExternalFilesDir().

Nor ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT for picking a file. Nor ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE for picking a directory.

No access to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data directory.

So what you are trying makes no sense for devices after Android Q.

Comment: It doesn't make sense since I can happily write files to that folder just fine.  I can't read them?  Or do I have to roll my own file picker to see them in a list?

Comment: If you can write them you can read them of course. And listing the content of a directory and putting it in an alert dialog is easy to do and see your own file picker us ready.